# Custom AlertDialog on Samsung One UI displays at bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile

I have implemented a custom AlertDialog for my app which works as intended with all devices I've tested except in particular for Samsung Devices running on Android 9 using the Samsung One UI. For the said Samsung devices, when I create the Dialog, it always shows up at the bottom of the screen rather than at the center.

**My Custom AlertDialog**

```
public static class DialogViewHolder {
        private CustomButton btnAccept, btnCancel;
        private CustomTextView title, message;
        private AlertDialog alertDialog;
        private View view;
        private Context context;
        private LinearLayout bg;

        public DialogViewHolder(Context context) {
            this.inflateView(context); // Should be the first
            this.buildAlertDialog(context);
            this.context = context;
        }

        /**
         * Inflates the custom view
         */
        private void inflateView(Context context) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            this.view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog, null);
        }

        /** Builds the alert Dialog */
        private void buildAlertDialog(Context context) {
            // Create Builder Configuration
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.CustomDialog);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setView(this.view);
        }
}
```

I've already tried playing with my layout files to make sure it wasn't a fluke but then I confirmed that this is only happening specifically on Samsung devices running Android Pie.

Was I correct to assume it had something to do with Samsung One UI? From what I've seen with the UI, most of the dialogs using said UI displays the alert dialog at the bottom of the screen. My end goal here is to be able to keep my custom AlertDialog in the middle of the screen.

**Layout of the Custom AlertDialog**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_bg_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/alert_background_color"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/logout_container_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/logout_padding_top"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/logout_padding_left_right"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/logout_padding_left_right">

            <com.example.dialog.custom_views.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/alert_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/logout_padding_top"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/alert_title_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/logout_header_title_size"
                app:font_trait="Bold" />

            <com.example.dialog.custom_views.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/alert_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/alert_header"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/data_usage_header_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/data_usage_header_margin"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/alert_negative_button_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/logout_message_size" />

            <com.example.dialog.custom_views.CustomButton
                android:id="@+id/positive_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/logout_button_height"
                android:layout_below="@+id/alert_message"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dialog_buttons_margin"
                android:background="@color/alert_positive_button_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/logout_buttons_text_size"
                app:font_trait="Normal"/>

            <com.example.dialog.custom_views.CustomButton
                android:id="@+id/negative_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/logout_button_height"
                android:layout_below="@+id/positive_button"
                android:background="@color/alert_negative_button_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/logout_buttons_text_size"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dialog_cancel_margin_bottom"
                app:font_trait="Normal">

            </com.example.dialog.custom_views.CustomButton>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html

Comment: @the_dani I guess thats what its called in Material but my code is supposed to create just a popup dialog box (which it does for all the phones I've tested it on except for the above mentioned Samsung phones)

Comment: do u solve this issue?

Comment: @tasjapr Yeah I think in the end we opted to use a third party library? Can't remember what it was, I left the job that had this code issue.